# Angular API Single object in how to bind category obj, subcategory object and group category object data

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular API Single object in how to bind category obj, subcategory object and group category object data

```
 let categoryObj = {
      'campaign_id': this.data.campaignId,
      'config_product_id': this.addProductObj.id,
      'product_code': this.addProductObj.product_code,
      'products_id': this.addProductObj.id
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
categoryGroupListData = [];
categoryListData = [];
subCategoryListData = [];

this.configProductCategoryForm = this.fb.group({
    'categoryGroupId': [data ? data.categoryGroupId : '', [Validators.required]],
    'categoryId': [data ? data.categoryId : '', [Validators.required]],
    'subCategoryId': [data ? data.subCategoryId : '', [Validators.required]],
});
```

```
 let catGroupDataObj = {
    configurable_product_id: id,
    category_group_id: value.categoryGroupId,
};
let catDataObj = {
    configurable_product_id: id,
    category_id: value.categoryId,
};
let subCatData = {
    configurable_product_id: id,
    sub_category_id: value.subCategoryId,
};
let MainData = {
    catGroupData: catGroupDataObj,
    catData: catDataObj,
    subCatData: subCatData
};

this.addConfigurableProductSaveCategory(MainData).subscribe((response: any) => { 
            });
```

Comment: welcome @Jaypalsinh you can change name accordingly to your data...